# Transaction for single class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, transactionscope

I've an asp.net application which take advantage of three tier layer:
DAL -> IUnitOfWork interface which implements EntityFramework
BLL -> set of business logic class where evenry class inherits from base business logic class 
UI -> web form

```
Base business logic class appears like following
public class BasebusinessLogicClass<TEntity>
ctor(IUnitOfWork uow){this.Unit = uow)
public void Insert(T entity) { // add entity on unit context and call SaveChanges}
public void Edit(T entity) { // edit entity on unit context and call SaveChanges}
public void Delete ..// as the above snippet..
```

As you can see on my code snippet, every business logica class execute "atomics" business operation. Every call to Insert, Delete, Edit method will call SaveChanges().
Now, I need to implement a sort of Transaction where its scope have to be limitated on class, for instance:

```
public class BusinessTransactionBase 
private collection of BusinessLogicBase;
public void Begin() {..initialize the TransactionScope class of .NET}
public void Commit() {Call Complete methid of transactionScope}
public void Rollback() {Dispose transasctionScope object}
public BusinessObjectBase<T> LoadBusinessObject<T>(){ return business logic base of T entity}
```

Well, what I'm looking for is to allowing to join on transaction the private collection of businessLogicBase only. So, if from another point someone execute something like "PersonLogicBase.Insert(T item).. AND my transaction will rollback, the PersonLogicBase.Insert(T item) will not affected by undo operation.

As far as I know, the only way to accomplish that is instantiate every BusinessTransaction object on separated thread, but I would using a better/simple solution.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit of work is that business transaction. If you need to execute all operation on given type in separate transaction you need a new instance of unit of work for that type. If you share your unit of work you will also share the business transaction.

Comment: I need to execute a real transaction, not just as EF means it. When I add a type T1, then I want read ID of that type in order to save T2 and decide best way to execute other stuff. In adding, please note that I can instantiate many ObjectContext, but all of them will share the same transactionScope since transactionScope wokr on thread layer.

Comment: In such case you don't need unit of work and you just need to ensure that contexts are not use by any other transaction.